# where clause doesn't work mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select random rows from a column however I have one problem, I would like to select a row where `title != '';` The below isn't giving me what I want.  I put `and r1.title != '';` This shows empty titles. I am echoing `$row['image_one'];` later. I have two rows, the first one has image_one and title, the second one has image_one and not title. it shows image_one with the title then when I refresh the page I get empty page. I want it to keep showing me only the image with title,

```
SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
FROM table AS r1 
    JOIN (
        SELECT (RAND() * (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)) AS id
    ) AS r2
WHERE 
    r1.id >= r2.id 
AND r1.title != '' 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1
```

The html

```
<?php include_once("models/config.php");?>
<div class="ho_col_1_pr">
 <?php 
    $stmt = $mydb->prepare("SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
            FROM hm_table AS r1 JOIN
               (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
             FROM table)) AS id)
            AS r2
     WHERE r1.id >= r2.id and r1.title != ''
     ORDER BY r1.id ASC
     LIMIT 1 ");
     $stmt->execute();
if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($mydb ->error));
} 

     ?>
  <?php      
$result = $stmt->get_result(); 
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
<div class="pro_img_wrap">

     <div class="hid_tit"><div class="hid_tit_ex"><?php echo wordwrap($row['title'], 50, "<br/>\n", true);?></div></div>

  <?php

  $path = 'images/';
  echo "<a href='test.php?redirect=".urlencode($row['title'])." & item=".$row['id']."'>"."<img src='".$path."".$row['image_one']."' style='width:225px;height:169px;'/>"."</a>";?>
    </div>
    <div class="pr_sep">
    <div class="pr_prod">
  <?php
  var_dump($row['title']) ;
  echo $row['price'];?>
  </div>
 <?php
 }
?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please define "doesn't work."

Comment: @MattBall it returns a row where `title = '';`

Comment: @Lmxc . . . Your SQL code *cannot* be returning a title that is `''`.  Perhaps there is a space or other unprintable character in the string, but the `where` clause is quite explicit.  Here are some possibilities:  (1) You have bad characters in the `title` string; (2) You have an error in your code that is displaying the title; (3) The query in your question is not the query really being used.  I would rule out a bug in MySQL for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the maximum id in the table has an empty title.  As a result, no records are matching when the random number generator is producing a value near 1, and your code is confusing a NULL value/empty row with an empty string.

You can fix this by modifying the query to some other method of getting a random row (as described in other answers).  You can also fix it with a small adjustment to your query.  First, here is a slight rewrite to your query (mostly eliminating the unnecessary subquery to get the max):

```
SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
FROM table r1 JOIN
     (SELECT RAND() * MAX(id) as id
      FROM table
     ) r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id AND r1.title != '' 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

The fix is to repeat the condition `title != ''` in the subquery:

```
SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
FROM table r1 JOIN
     (SELECT RAND() * MAX(id) as id
      FROM table
      WHERE title != ''
     ) r2
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id AND r1.title != '' 
ORDER BY r1.id ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Of course, a simpler way to do what you want is simply:

```
SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
FROM table r1
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

However, this does have issues with scalability on largish tables.

Comment: Thanks I used the first solution and it worked but will it have impact on how fast it retrieves the row?

Comment: @Lmxc . . . The impact depends on the data and indexes.  If you have an index on `id`, then the `where` clause will have a big impact on performance.  I think you could fix it by putting an index on `title, id` and changing the condition to `title > ''`.

Comment: When you said index, is it doing something like `ALTER TABLE tbname ADD INDEX ( columnname ) ;` in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

This is because `NULL` is not the same as `''`. If you need to find not empty titles, you need to change the query to:

```
 SELECT r1.id, title, price, image_one
            FROM table AS r1 JOIN
               (SELECT (RAND() *
                 (SELECT MAX(id)
             FROM table)) AS id)
            AS r2
     WHERE r1.id >= r2.id AND r1.title IS NOT NULL AND r1.title != '' 
     ORDER BY r1.id ASC
     LIMIT 1
```

Or better to:

```
SELECT id, title, price, image_one FROM (
    SELECT id, title, price, image_one, RAND() as rnd
      FROM table
     WHERE title IS NOT NULL AND title != '' 
  ORDER BY rnd
) s
LIMIT  1;
```

Comment: This _may_ be because the field value is null, but you can compare an empty string in this manner so it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: As in comment to the main thread - `it returns a row where title = '';` :-)

Comment: @Lmxc, as has been stated earlier _"doesn't work"_ is the most useless thing you can write. You need to either provide an error message or a description of the problem, for example _"now no rows are returned"_. If you want real help with your question it's often easier to provide sample data and a sample output.

Comment: as I am echoing later `$row['image_one']`, it shows image_one with empty title;

Comment: You are echoing `$row['image_one']` and it shows empty `title`? How can it show `title` when you echo `image_one`? And how the hell it is possible that it **shows** `empty` thing when it is `empty`?

Comment: @FlashThunder I said it shows image_one with empty title. doesn't `title != '';` mean title different from empty or not empty?

Comment: `I am echoing $row['image_one']; later and it shows image_one with empty title` ... anyway, do `var_dump($row['title']`) for row that shows empty title, and paste the results.

Comment: @FlashThunder okay I might have been confused, I have two rows one with a title and another with empty title. I just want it to return only the row with the title. first it shows me the image with title then when I hit refresh it goes blank. I want it to keep showing me the image with title.

Comment: Every first page enter it shows title and every refresh id doesn't? Then the problem is somewhere else. Show full HTML and PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WHERE r1.id >= r2.id and char_length(coalesce(r1.title,'')) > 0
```

Comment: Still I can see rows with empty title.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `r1.title <> ''`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: `!=` and `<>` are synonyms.